# cygwin cmake unable to find boost libraries

Tags: boost, cmake, cygwin

I know this has been asked several times, but I seem to have set all the required variables correctly and cmake keeps not finding the required components.

I successfully (with struggle...) compiled boost libraries and they have this file structure:

```
C:\boost_1_57_0 
   | - android
   |    | - lib
   |         | - libboost_date_time-gcc-mt-s-1_57.a
   |         | - libboost_random-gcc-mt-s-1_57.a
   |         | - libboost_system-gcc-mt-s-1_57.a
   | - boost
        | - date_time
        |    | - *.hpp
        | - random
        |    | - *.hpp
        | - system
            | - *.hpp
```

This is the relevant part of my cmake:

```
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build the shared library" OFF)
option(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS "Use Boost static version" ON)

set(BOOST_VER "1.57.0" CACHE STRING "boost version" )
set(BOOST_ROOT "/cygdrive/c/boost_1_57_0/")
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "/cygdrive/c/boost_1_57_0/boost/")
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "/cygdrive/c/boost_1_57_0/android/lib/")
# I tried also C: instead of /cygdrive/c, with no success

message(STATUS "BOOST_ROOT = ${BOOST_ROOT}")
message(STATUS "BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = ${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR}")
message(STATUS "BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = ${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR}")

set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON) 
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF) 
find_package(Boost ${BOOST_VER} REQUIRED COMPONENTS system date_time random)
```

and this is the output that I get:

```
$ cmake ./
-- not define build type, set to release
-- BOOST_ROOT = /cygdrive/c/boost_1_57_0/
-- BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = /cygdrive/c/boost_1_57_0/boost/
-- BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = /cygdrive/c/boost_1_57_0/android/lib/
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.3.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1245 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.57.0

  Boost include path: /cygdrive/c/boost_1_57_0

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_system
          boost_date_time
          boost_random

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:32 (find_package)
```

Why is it not working? And why I set `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` to `/cygdrive/c/boost_1_57_0/boost/` but he seems to ignore it and look for the include files in `whatever I set BOOST_ROOT to`? And why is he ignoring `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` too?

Comment: You are cross compiling for Android. Have you told to cmake which is the cross-compiler ?

Comment: @matzeri yes; but I'm stuck a step before.

Comment: `BOOST_ROOT` has priority against `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` and `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` when search things. As headers are found under `BOOST_ROOT`, other directories are not searched. As for main question - libraries are not found - set `Boost_DEBUG` variable and check debug messages which will be shown during configuration. They should get a key to the problem. Probably, filenames of libraries which you have doesn't fit into `FindBoost.cmake` script's expectations.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the cause of my problem.
First of all I had to

```
set(Boost_DEBUG 1)
```

in my CMakeLists.txt, so that FindBoost.cmake, called by `find_package(Boost ${BOOST_VER} ... )` could print what he was searching.

So I found out that the problem was that:

```
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.3.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:827 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = -gcc46
```

while it should be `-gcc`, and that:

```
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.3.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1052 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_system-gcc46-mt-1_57
```

So I found out that the variable `Boost_LIB_PREFIX` was not set.

The first problem was due to the `_Boost_GUESS_COMPILER_PREFIX` function in FindBoost.cmake. For some reason, I had these variables:

```
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID : GNU #why?? I'm using Cygwin under Windows...
MINGW :  #unset 
UNIX : 1 
CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX : 1
Boost_MAJOR_VERSION : 1
Boost_MINOR_VERSION : 57
```

So at a certain point:

```
if(${Boost_MAJOR_VERSION}.${Boost_MINOR_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 1.34)
    set(_boost_COMPILER "-gcc") # no GCC version encoding prior to 1.34
else()
    ....
    set(_boost_COMPILER "-gcc${_boost_COMPILER_VERSION}")
endif()
```

The second problem was due to these lines in FindBoost.cmake:

```
set(Boost_LIB_PREFIX "")
if ( (GHSMULTI AND Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS) OR
    (WIN32 AND Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS AND NOT CYGWIN) )
  set(Boost_LIB_PREFIX "lib")
endif()
```

I still don't understand why it should not add the prefix "lib" with cygwin.

Eventually, I don't know exactly why he was searching for the wrong library names, maybe I messed up and compiled with different tools/versions.